# How to create Javascript constructor/prototype with unassigned properties?

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor, prototype

I'm coming at this from the OOP world and trying to wrap my head around "classes" in Javascript.  I'd like to be able to create a class with properties but not have to assign values to them right away.  Something like the following:

```
var MyObject = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
    // Create the property so it is present on all instances but don't require it to be assigned to right away.
    this.friendId;
}

MyObject.prototype = {
    constructor: MyObject

    // Etc...
}
```

Is there a way to do this or am I just not getting how it works in Javascript?

Comment: `this.friendId = null`

Comment: JavaScript really doesn't have "classes". Trying to make it act like that is a good way to frustrate yourself.

Comment: Why do you need it "present" instead of just pretending it exists everywhere and assigning it when you need it (duck typing)?

Comment: Yeah, I know that I'll need to change the way I think about things when working in Javascript.  Just trying to find a starting point.

Comment: The words "JavaScript" and "class" don't really go so well together. JavaScript is a prototype-based language instead of a class-based language.

Comment: What got me on this "class" path was looking at the code for Twitter Bootstrap.  E.g., http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js

Comment: What is the point of a property with no value? Given that javascript is loosely typed, there isn't much point to creating a property until you are ready to assign a value. BTW, Peter's comment does assign a value, the *null* value, so it's doing exactly what you apprently didn't want to do. :-)

Comment: I'm cool with it initializing to null, I just didn't want to have to pass in an actual known value to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply omit the property from the declaration:

```
function MyObject(id) 
{
    this.id = id;
}

var obj = new MyObject(123);
console.log(obj.friendId); // undefined
```

Alternatively, explicitly set it to `null` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This Mozilla Developer Network article is a good read.
It compares Class based and Prototype based languages and provides side by side codes samples in Java and in JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Quoting from the article.

> Constructor function or prototype specifies an *initial* set of properties. Can add or remove properties dynamically to individual objects or to the entire set of objects.

Comment: In that doc, it has examples with constructors that initialize "empty" properties, i.e. not assigning an actual value to them, which is what I was trying to accomplish.